# 8 - Translate static content

Tags: theming, 8

In my site there are lot of static content such as section headers and random content. I want to translate them.

Can I translate with them `{% trans %}my content{% endtrans %}` in twig?

If yes, where to insert the translations in the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can do it hardcoded in twig, this can be translated via the user interface translation: `/admin/config/regional/translate`. The `locale` module needs to be enabled.

> **BUT**, i would only recommend this method for static content (and maybe random)!

For dynamic content i suggest to use the drupal multilingual feature(s). Start by enabling the module `content_translation`.
Then you can edit a node, and add a translation for it in the backend (node/x/edit). See the docs on [d.o.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual) for further information.